# Itertools Zip Two List into each other

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
c = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(list_a, list_b)))
```

I have two list `list_a` and `list_b`

`list_a` has one more element than `list_b` and i want to insert between two elements of a one element of b.

Unfortunately this method from above deletes the last element of `list_a` in the result list c.
How can i fix this?
Python 2.7

Comment: "i want to insert between two elements of a one element of b" ... is quite confusing ... can you plz clarify ?

Comment: So if `list_a` is `[0,2,4,6,8]` and `list_b` is `[1,3,5,7]` you want `list_c` to be `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about `itertools` to say much more, but if you only need to append the last element of `list_a` to `c`, why not do just that?

```
import itertools

list_a = [1,3,5,7,9]
list_b = [2,4,6,8]

c = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(list_a, list_b)))
# c is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

c.append(list_a[-1])
# after append c is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```